# value is not passed by javascript function to php file

Tags: javascript, php

i'm newbie to javascript
and i have create a function by myself but it's not working

```
function oi_delete(ns_oi){
alert("Are You Sure About DELETE image # " + ns_oi + " ?");
$.post('insert.php', {ns_oi:ns_oi});
location.reload();}
```

alert and location is working but seconde line:    $.post('insert.php', {ns_oi:ns_oi});
is not working or maybe working wrong!

i have create this function to send a value "ns_oi" to insert.php
and in insert.php i have get that value and do something

can anyone help me and say what is the problem?

Comment: You're using AJAX, why you want to reload whole page?

Comment: You're doing `location.reload` which refreshes the page instantly. The `$.post` request is asynchronous, it doesn't get the chance to fire before you reload. You can do `$.post('insert.php', {ns_oi:ns_oi}).done(function(){ location.reload;})` but you should probably rethink your logic. Why is that `location.reload` there?

Comment: Note that `alert()` won't allow the user to click *No*. Use [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send it properly with a `jQuery.post()` function properly like:

```
function oi_delete(ns_oi){
    alert("Are You Sure About DELETE image # " + ns_oi + " ?");

    $.post('insert.php', {ns_oi:ns_oi}, function(data) {
        location.reload();
    });

}
```